# ScrollView contentView size not changing accordingly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I have a `ScrollView` in which I change its `contentSize` (the height to be specific). When I do this, the `ContentView`'s size that is attached to the `ScrollView` doesn't change accordingly.

The `ContentView`'s `height` and `width` is equal to the `ScrollView`, and the `priority` is 250 (height).

See my constraints:

[image: Storjboard Constraints]

for test purposes I changes the height of the contentSize to this:

```
 scrollView.contentSize.height += self.postedImageView.getImageHeight(forImage: selectedImage)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't change `scrollView.contentSize` with autolayout contentsize is changed by the `contentView`

Comment: if I do this the scrollview doesn't scroll anymore:         `contentView.frame.size.height += self.postedImageView.getImageHeight(forImage: selectedImage)`

Comment: Why do you change contentView.frame ? Chagen postedImageView height constraint value

Comment: But the height constraint is equal to the scrollview height. As you can see in the picture. Does that matter?

Comment: As you've changed its priority to 250, contentview's height will be changed by its subviews

Comment: by changing the posted image height which is initially 0 the height of scrollview/ content view still not changes

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `contentSize.height` directly. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245318/going-crazy-with-uiscrollview-and-storyboard-constraints/56248208#56248208) very similar question.

Basically you want

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height + self.postedImageView.getImageHeight(forImage: selectedImage))
```

**EDIT:** from your comment

Why don't you just:

```
scrollView.ContentView.frame = CGRect(x: scrollView.ContentView.frame.origin.x, y: scrollView.ContentView.frame.origin.y, width: scrollView.ContentView.frame.width, height: scrollView.ContentView.frame.height + self.postedImageView.getImageHeight(forImage: selectedImage))
```

At the same time as you adjust the content size?

Or this:

```
scrollView.ContentView.frame = CGRect(x: scrollView.ContentView.frame.origin.x, y: scrollView.ContentView.frame.origin.y, width: scrollView.ContentView.frame.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
```

Comment: but then the content views height stays the same

Comment: Value of type 'UIScrollView?' has no member 'ContentView'

Comment: well however you can reference your `ContentView` e.g. as an outlet, do it that way...